# Am I allowed to ask "How to get started" questions here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

By this, I don't mean questions about how to get started as a programmer. Instead, when I want to implement something new, can I ask for advice on how to tackle the problem? For example, do questions that ask for a common approach fit this site?

Comment: It is an area that is fraught with peril because many of the questions are too broad.  Suggested reading: [Where to start](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start) for information on why this often has trouble, the common pitfalls and some options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, the answer is "**No!**"

How to get started questions are usually too broad and don't have a specific, answerable question. So they tend to be closed quickly and potentially heavily down voted.

That said, beginner / inexperienced questions are OK if there is a specific problem that's answerable.  For example, say you're trying to learn pointer arithmetic and manipulation.  And you don't understand how a second de-reference operates or you're trying to understand what the reference operators correspond to within the computer's memory.  Those are specific issues within the subject that you're trying to learn and would likely be on-topic for questions.